# how can I solve this error when I want to install gulp-sass on mac with npm

Tags: macos, npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/aliabniki/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/15.3.0/bin/node     /Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --    libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.3.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli       '/Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.3.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.16
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node     version: 15.3.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '15.3.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "15.3.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 15.3.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 15.3.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir:     /Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created?     /Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file:     /Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file:     /Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file:     /Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args       '/Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args       '/Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args       '/Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-    sass/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/aaa/.node-gyp/15.3.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/aliabniki/.node-gyp/15.3.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-    Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules/gu    lp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/aliabniki/.node-    gyp/15.3.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-    Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/aaa/Sites/projects/PracticeProjects/MiniProjects/test/node_modules    /gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
```

this error occures when I want to install gulp-sass with npm package

```
sudo npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

node-sass installation has no problem but gulp-sass can not be installed
please help me to solve this problem

I have installed sass with npm and other packages like "browser-sync" or "gulp-cli" installed correctly but "gulp-sass" have not been installed anyway!

Comment: As the error says, `npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!`, have you tried `sudo xcode-select --reset`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when attempting to install gulp-sass and node-sass onto a Mac Mini M1 with macOS 11.3. The solution suggested 'sudo xcode-select --reset' resolved the problem and allowed me to get the needed packages installed.

Thanks,